# Issue in installing ADB drivers for nook 1.4.2 in windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7-x64, nook, nook-tablet

I am new to android development and I need to test my application on nook color/tablet for that I have got provision.cmd and copied to root of my nook color/tablet.

But running "adb devices" still does not show nook. although device is connected, but when I tried to connect some other device say nexus then running the same command "adb devices" show the connected device.

I have read a lot of forums about that some suggest to install drivers for nook but windows already have installed drivers for the device and updating it does not work as windows says that drivers for devices are already up to date.

please guide me where possibly I am doing wrong.

Regards 
Ahsan

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for quite a while, finally got it working.  Log in as a Nook developer, then follow this thread:

https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21458241

You need a provision.cmd file in order to debug the device, which means you need a developer account.